# Correct term for "primary" and "secondary" hand

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for the correct term for a right-handed person's right hand, and a left-handed person's left hand, and same for their other hand, where one term signifies one's "primary" hand, and the other one's "secondary" hand.

Comment: I voted for "dominant hand", but you may also refer to "preferential hand". For the opposite, "non-dominant hand" fits.

Comment: "dominant" takes the cake in my book but I wonder if you could describe a perfectly ambidextrous person this way? In this context, my understanding is that dominant would mean that nothing is equal nor better.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Someone who is perfectly ambidextrous does not fit within the question's scope anyway, they don't have a primary/secondary hand distinction.

Comment: 21 upvotes for the top answer and only 4 for OP?  Come on English.SE...

Comment: Maybe it's somewhat of a stupid question :-)

Comment: It's a rather vaguely worded question. From the title alone, a bridge player might have assumed the OP wanted the terms "declarer" and "dummy".

Answer (score 35):

The "primary" hand is generally called ***dominant***.

> **Dominant hand**
>
> Operant hand generally used for performing fine motor-skills tasks (e.g., writing, holding dental instruments)
>
> Medical Dictionary for the Dental Professions © Farlex 2012 via [TFD](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/dominant+hand)

From that, I would surmise *subordinate hand* for the other one.

Comment: I usually hear "non-dominant hand" as the alternative.

Comment: I would say that your speculation is just wrong: [_subordinate hand_ is almost never used](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_start=1800&content=dominant+hand%2Cnon-dominant+hand%2Csubordinate+hand&corpus=15&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdominant%20hand%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnon%20-%20dominant%20hand%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csubordinate%20hand%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: As per @PhilSweet's answer below, "off hand" or "weak hand" are commonly used for the non-dominant hand. While "subordinate" technically works, the word is more commonly used to indicate hierarchy or control (e.g. boss/subordinates), and the dominant hand generally exerts no direct control over the off hand.

Answer (score 23):

The non-dominant hand is commonly called the **off hand**. Also the **weak hand**. See any combat arts forum.

http://www.bladeforums.com/forums/showthread.php/206957-Question-Knife-position-Dominant-Hand-or-Off-Hand